# Rails4 reject_if and validation not working: unable to save without nested objects

Tags: validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have these two models

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order, :inverse_of => :transaction, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order, :allow_destroy=> true, :reject_if=> :menu_id_validation
  def menu_id_validation(attributes)
    attributes['menu_id'].blank?
  end
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transaction, :inverse_of => :order
  belongs_to :menu
  validates :menu_id, :presence => true
  validates_presence_of :transaction
end
```

When I send parameters like this to create a transaction:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...",
"transaction"=>{..., "customer_id"=>"30", "staff_id"=>"8", 
"order_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"menu_id"=>"", "price"=>"", "num"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, 
"1"=>{"menu_id"=>"", "price"=>"", "num"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, 
"2"=>{"menu_id"=>"", "price"=>"", "num"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"},
"3"=>{"menu_id"=>"", "price"=>"", "num"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}}},
"commit"=>"save”}
```

I expect :reject_if to discard all of the order parameters, because none of them has 'menu_id' and actually :menu_id_validation returns true for them.
However, I couldn't save this and got the order model's validation error of :menu.

Very weird thing, I can save this by filling at least one of order parameters to have :menu_id.
And if I save a transaction model object with some order model object, I can remove all of them like this.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
"transaction"=>{...,"customer_id"=>"10", "staff_id"=>"8",
"order_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"menu_id"=>"", "price"=>"", "num"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"true", "id"=>"219"}, 
"1"=>{"menu_id"=>"", "price"=>"", "num"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, 
"2"=>{"menu_id"=>"", "price"=>"", "num"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, 
"3"=>{"menu_id"=>"", "price"=>"", "num"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}},},
"commit"=>"save", "id"=>"108"}
```

The first parameters are already saved in db and going to be destroyed by "_destroy"=>true. By this, all of nested order model objects are removed.But this can be saved.

I think this problem is caused by the conflict(?) between validation of order and :reject_if.
What should I do to save transaction model object even if it is not saved yet and has no order model object?

Answer (score 0):

I think `:reject_if` will only take the name of a method **on the associated model** (in this case, `Order`), such as `:new_record?` or a proc, that acts upon the nested attribute hash, like `proc {|attrs| attrs['menu_id'].blank? }`.
So you would either want to use a proc (a good idea, since your condition appears to be only one line), or define `:menu_id_validation` within your `Order` model instead of within `Transaction`.

Comment: Did this sufficiently answer your question? Did it help? If so, would sure be nice if you'd accept my answer.